# Laravel 5.2 フォーム入力後、メールが送信されない

Tags: laravel

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;

use Illuminate\Mail\Message;

use Session;



class ContactController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Welcomeコントローラー
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | このコントローラーはアプリケーションの「マーケティングページ」を
    | レンダーし、ゲストのみに表示されるように設定されています。
    | 他のコントローラサンプルと同様、好きなように変更したり、削除してください。
    |
    */

    /**
     * 新しいコントローラーインスタンスの生成
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        #$this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * アプリケーションのウェルカムページをユーザーへ表示
     * 非ログインTOPページ
     * @param bool|false $open
     * @return $this
     */


    /**
     * お問合せフォーム
     */
    public function getIndex(Request $request)
    {
        // $test = Session::get('set_category');
        $test1 = Session::get('set_category1');

        $test2 = $request->session()->get('set_category2');

        return view('contact.index');
    }

    /**
     * 確認処理
     */
    public function postConfirm(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'locations' => 'required',
            'situation' => 'required',
            'generation' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'prefectures' => 'required',
            'movein' => 'required',
            'tel' => 'required|numeric',
            'return' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',


        ]);
        \Session::flash("request", $request->all());
        return redirect('contact/confirm');
    }

    /**
     * 確認ページ
     */
    public function getConfirm()
    {
        if (!\Session::has('request')) {
            return redirect('contact');
        }
        $request = \Session::get('request');
        \Session::keep(['request']);

        return view('contact.confirm', $request);
    }

    /**
     * メール送信処理
     * Todo:メール送信先を設定に加える
     */
    public function postSend(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'locations' => 'required',
            'situation' => 'required',
            'generation' => 'required',
            'generation' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'prefectures' => 'required',
            'movein' => 'required',
            'tel' => 'required|numeric',
            'return' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',

        ]);

        $data = $request->all();
        \Session::flash("request", $data);

        \Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
            $message->to('sample@〇〇.jp', '〇〇 サポートセンター')->subject('【】お問合せフォーム');
        });
        return redirect('contact/send');
    }

    /**
     * 送信完了ページ
     */
    public function getSend()
    {
        return view('contact.send');
    }

}
```

フォーム入力後、送信してもメールが送信されません。
理由わかりますでしょうか。

上記フォーム部分のコントローラーになります。

Answer (score 1):

何かエラーが発生していないでしょうか。

私の場合は

```
FatalErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 344:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

が発生して送信ができませんでした。

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
\Mail::send(...
```

でエラーにならずにメールが送信できるようになりました。
参考になれば幸いです。